# Unable to convert data types when looping through a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to loop through a list of dictionaries and convert their datatype based on a reference to another configuration dictionary which contains the datatypes I want to convert to.

The config dictionary is the following:

```
search_results_config = {

    'id':'int',
    'description':'string',
    'page':'int',
    'position':'int',
    'title':'string',
    'type':'int',
    'typedescription':'string',
    'url':'string'
}
```

And the list of dictionaries that I am actually trying to loop through `top_rank_data` and change datatypes of looks like the following:

```
 {
        'description': 'Churchill contents insurance covers the things that matter most in your home. We offer cover of up to £50,000 as\xa0',
        'position': 18, 'page': 2, 'title': 'Contents insurance | Home Insurance | Churchill UK', 'type': '0',
        'typedescription': 'organic', 'url': 'https://www.churchill.com/home-insurance/options/contents'}, {
        'description': 'Compare contents insurance and how to cut the cost of home contents insurance cover for your personal possessions\xa0',
        'position': 19, 'page': 2, 'title': 'Contents Insurance - compare cheap contents insurance', 'type': '0',
        'typedescription': 'organic', 'url': 'https://www.uswitch.com/home-insurance/contents-insurance/'}
```

Code below is:

```
for row in top_rank_data:

    for item in row:

        for key, value in search_results_config.items():
            new_value = None
            config_type = search_results_config[key]

        if config_type == 'string':
            new_value = str(value) or ''

        if config_type == 'int':
            new_value = int(value) or 9
```

So I expect the value of any key to change data type as per the `search_results_config` dictionary. Instead I only get back `string` datatype for all, so I presume the `if config_type` statements are not working. Any help much appreciated!

Additional function which is generating data:

```
path = 'C:\downloaded'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.json')):
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as currentFile:
        data = currentFile.read()
        rank_data = json.loads(data)["rankdata"]

        for entry in rank_data:
            if (entry["page"]) <= 2 and (entry["typedescription"]) == "organic":
                top_rank_data.append(entry)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a version to do that:

```
search_results_config = {

    'id': int,
    'description': str,
    'page': int,
    'position': int,
    'title': str,
    'type': int,
    'typedescription': str,
    'url': str
}

items = ({
        'description': 'Churchill contents insurance covers the things that matter most in your home. We offer cover of up to £50,000 as\xa0',
        'position': 18, 'page': 2, 'title': 'Contents insurance | Home Insurance | Churchill UK', 'type': '0',
        'typedescription': 'organic', 'url': 'https://www.churchill.com/home-insurance/options/contents'}, {
        'description': 'Compare contents insurance and how to cut the cost of home contents insurance cover for your personal possessions\xa0',
        'position': 19, 'page': 2, 'title': 'Contents Insurance - compare cheap contents insurance', 'type': '0',
        'typedescription': 'organic', 'url': 'https://www.uswitch.com/home-insurance/contents-insurance/'})

def convert(dct):
    return {key: search_results_config[key](value) for key, value in dct.items()}


for dct in items:
    print(convert(dct))
```

note that `search_results_config` directly contains the types (i.e. `int` instead of `'int'`) that are used in order to convert your data.

---

you can also add a default type (i used `str` in the example below) for `key`s  that do not exist in `search_results_config`:

```
def convert(dct):
    return {key: search_results_config.get(key, str)(value) 
            for key, value in dct.items()}
```

Comment: Thanks this works! Only issue is when I try it with all of the original data I get the error `Type = search_results_config[key] KeyError: 'snippets'` I have added function which generates data to the end of the question to see if anything is visible here which may be causing this?

Comment: Is there a way to add the handling of missing values as per the original example? So in the case of string if no value is present it would add a space, and in the case of int it would add a 9 as default value?

Comment: instead of just the 'standard' converter (i,e, `int`) you could always define a converter of your own `def to_my_int(value): return int(value) or 9` and add `to_my_int` to the dictionary for the field in question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Approach:

```
New_List = []
for dictionary in top_rank_data:
    Sub_Dict = {}
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        Type = search_results_config[key]
        try:
            New_Val = Type(value)
        except:
            New_Val = value

        Sub_Dict[key] = New_Val

    New_List.append(Sub_Dict)
```